# Finding supremum (Uniform convergence and integration).

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Question:

Let $f_n(x)=xn(1-x^2)^n$ on domain $[0,1]$. Verify that the pointwise limit function is the zero function through domain.

Prove that $\displaystyle\int f_n=n/(2n+2)$ on $[0,1]$ and deduce that

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\neq\int\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$.

Is the convergence of the sequence uniform?

What is $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}sup{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:0\le x\le1}$?

It is pretty clear that $f_n(x)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ for $0\le x\le1$. Using integration by substitution we can get $\int f_n$.

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n= \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $\displaystyle\int\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=0$.

Until now it is pretty easy and clear for me. The supremum part is where I don't understand.

$$ sup{|f_n(x)-f(x)|:0\le x\le 1=\dfrac{n}{(\sqrt{1+2n})\cdot (1+\dfrac{1}{2n})^n\to\infty $$.

I don't know how they get to this but my answer is kinda different. Since $f(x)$ is 0 then

$sup{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}=0$

and thus it is uniformly convergent. I think I am wrong and right at same time. Can somebody explain this step? Also there this written in answer which I think is kinda useless but you might have better idea why it was with answer

$f'_n(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}})=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does $\sup_x |f_n(x)-0| \to 0$? $f_n(x) \to 0$ for each $x$ does not imply that the supremum tends to $0$. You have to find the maximum of $f_n(x)$ by setting the derivative equal to $0$ which gives $x=\frac 1 {\sqrt {2n+1}}$. The maximum value turns out to be $\frac n {\sqrt {2n+1}} (1-\frac 1 {2n+1})^{n}$ and the limit of this is $\infty$.

Comment: But derivative equal to 0 doesn't imply that it is maximum value.

Comment: $f_n$ vanishes at the end points $0$ and $1$. Hence the maximum value is attained at a  point in  $(0,1)$ where the derivative must vanish. @2Balls1Bat

Comment: The comment answer didn't quiet satisfied me. Yes $f_n$ vanishes at the end points 0 and 1 and maximum value is attained at a point in(0,1) where derivative must vanish but this still doesn't tell me about it is maximum or minimum.

Comment: @2Balls1Bat Being a continuous function it must attain its maximum at some point which we know must be in $(0,1)$. At this point the derivative is $0$. But we have found that derivative is $0$ at only one point, namely $\frac 1  {\sqrt {2n+1}}$. So the maximum value must be at this point.

Comment: I know that but I forgot to mention that it can also be minimum by maximum-minimum theorem. You need to test it whether it is maximum or minimum. But anyway I know it is maximum since bound value of function is zero and 0 derivative give only one point which is greater than bound value of function so it is maximum. I was expecting local maximum or minimum test which is tedious. Now it's clear and I was fool for expecting that.